# How to make the vba code to auto update by row?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, file-copying

I have many files in a folder,

I have my code as below, is there any way to simplified my code so I do not need to keep copy and paste the same code but just continue updating the row number?

```
Sub FetchData()
Dim wbSource As Workbook
Dim shSource As Worksheet
Dim shDestin As Worksheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'trace file from file path on B12
Workbooks.Open Filename:=Range("B12").Value & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
Set wbSource = ActiveWorkbook
Set shSource = wbSource.Sheets("Sheet1")

'current sheet display
Set shDestin = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

'shDestion.Range display at where shSource.Range: the track data frm other file (NI)
shDestin.Range("E12") = shSource.Range("C2")
shDestin.Range("F12") = shSource.Range("D2")
shDestin.Range("G12") = shSource.Range("E2")

'shDestion.Range display at where shSource.Range: the track data frm other file (PD)
shDestin.Range("N12") = shSource.Range("C3")
shDestin.Range("O12") = shSource.Range("D3")
shDestin.Range("P12") = shSource.Range("E3")

 'shDestion.Range display at where shSource.Range: the track data frm other file (AU)
  shDestin.Range("W12") = shSource.Range("C4")
  shDestin.Range("X12") = shSource.Range("D4")
  shDestin.Range("Y12") = shSource.Range("E4")

‘copy from another workbook where filepath is at B11
Workbooks.Open Filename:=Range("B11").Value & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A4")
Set wbSource = ActiveWorkbook
Set shSource = wbSource.Sheets("Sheet1")

'current sheet display
Set shDestin = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

'shDestion.Range display at where shSource.Range: the track data frm other file (NI)
shDestin.Range("E11") = shSource.Range("C2")
shDestin.Range("F11") = shSource.Range("D2")
shDestin.Range("G11") = shSource.Range("E2")

   'shDestion.Range display at where shSource.Range: the track data frm other file (PD)
  shDestin.Range("N11") = shSource.Range("C3")
  shDestin.Range("O11") = shSource.Range("D3")
  shDestin.Range("P11") = shSource.Range("E3")

  'shDestion.Range display at where shSource.Range: the track data frm other file (AU)
  shDestin.Range("W11") = shSource.Range("C4")
  shDestin.Range("X11") = shSource.Range("D4")
  shDestin.Range("Y11") = shSource.Range("E4")

wbSource.Close False
End Sub
```

Comment: what piece of code are you copy/pasting? all of it or just some of it? Where is the row number you are referring to? is it in the code or on the Excel worksheet?

Comment: There is certainly some way to optimize this, for example you could do `shDestin.Range("E12:G12") = shSource.Range("C2:E2")`, etc., But I think there is further room to improve it if you need to do this in a loop/repetition.

Comment: The code is in the Excel file, I have set a button to trace some of the data from multiple files.
The row number will be the one that I wish shDestin.Range row number.
Is it possible that I can do a loop?

Comment: When I input   shDestin.Range("E12:G12") = shSource.Range("C2:E2"), it show type mismatch.

Comment: Your problem statement isn't clear. You need to use loops. But I dont rule out the possibility of being able to do this without any VBA at all. Also, for statements such as these, shDestin.Range("E11") = shSource.Range("C2"), you need to use shDestin.Range("E11").value = shSource.Range("C2").value else it will throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, but it's hard to tell exactly what you're doing in the code you posted...

For example what's the Activesheet when you start this code?

```
Option Explicit

Sub FetchData()

    Dim shDestin As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set shDestin = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    CopyFileContent Range("B12").Value & shDestin.Range("A1").Value, _
                    shDestin, 12

    CopyFileContent Range("B11").Value & shDestin.Range("A4").Value, _
                    shDestin, 11

End Sub


Sub CopyFileContent(filePath As String, destSheet As Worksheet, destRow As Long)

    Dim wbSource As Workbook, shSource As Worksheet, rngDest As Range

    Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=filePath)
    Set shSource = wbSource.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Set rngDest = destSheet.Cells(destRow, 5).Resize(1, 3)
    rngDest.Value = shSource.Range("C2:E2").Value
    rngDest.Offset(0, 9).Value = shSource.Range("C3:E3").Value
    rngDest.Offset(0, 18).Value = shSource.Range("C4:E4").Value

    wbSource.Close False
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi,
It works!Thank a lots.
But can I know what is the meaning for 
    rngDest.Offset(0, 9).Value 
    rngDest.Offset(0, 18).Value 

Thank you.

Comment: rngDest is a range variable which refers to "E{r}:F{r}" where {r} is the row number passed in to the procedure. `rngDest.Offset(0, 9)` refers to the range 9 columns to the right of that (on the same row).  The range's `Value` is a 2-d array of values, which can be assigned directly to another range of the same size and orientation.

Comment: Thank for your explanation.
I was wondering that if the file path on B12 is empty, is there any method to make it don't run the CopyFileContent function?

Because if I proceed to use the code, it will come out error if it detect B12 is empty.

Does IsEmpty() will be able help on the code?

Comment: You can use something like `If Len(Range("B12").Value) > 0 Then`

Comment: Hi,there is nothing come out after I modify my code as below, no error, but no data being trace out

         If Len(Range("B12").Value) > 0 Then
    
         Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=filePath)
         Set shSource = wbSource.Sheets("Sheet1")

Comment: That If should be used to decide whether to call the Sub, not in the sub itself.